# html: hover table column

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-tables

How can I change the background column of an html table **column** when the mouse is over it?

Preferably with css only.

Comment: Here is a great post (not mine):

https://css-tricks.com/simple-css-row-column-highlighting/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only works for cells or rows, sorry. 
e.g.

```css
td {
  background-color: blue;
}

td:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

There are JavaScript solutions available but nothing in CSS right now will do what you want because of the limitations of selectors.

```css
td  /* all cells */
{ 
  background-color: blue;
}

tr /* all rows */
{
  background-color: pink;
}

/* nothing for all columns */
```

Comment: Actually you can style columns using either the sibling selector (gets a little messy) or CSS3's `nth-child` (no IE support). You still can't do it on hover though, because you're only ever hovering on a cell or row, not a column.

Answer (score 54):

This can be done using CSS with no Javascript.

I used the `::after` pseudo-element to do the highlighting. `z-index` keeps the highlighting below the `<tds>` in case you need to handle click events. Using a massive height allows it to cover the whole column. `overflow: hidden` on the `<table>` hides the highlight overflow.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/2XeYe/

Output:

[image]

CSS:

```css
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}

td, th {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

td:hover::after { 
    background-color: #ffa;
    content: '\00a0';  
    height: 10000px;    
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;  
    top: -5000px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;        
}
```

HTML:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th><th>50kg</th><th>55kg</th><th>60kg</th><th>65kg</th><th>70kg</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>160cm</th><td>20</td><td>21</td><td>23</td><td>25</td><td>27</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>165cm</th><td>18</td><td>20</td><td>22</td><td>24</td><td>26</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>170cm</th><td>17</td><td>19</td><td>21</td><td>23</td><td>25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>175cm</th><td>16</td><td>18</td><td>20</td><td>22</td><td>24</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I am not sure your FF fix worked.  The body's background changes to yellow rather than just the column on hover.

Comment: @vulpix This works for me on FF14 on OS X.

Comment: -1 Does not work with IE at all.

Comment: @BorisYankov Works in IE9 on Windows7 for me.

Comment: Wasn't working on IE10. Tested with IE Tester and it appears it works _only_ on IE9, not on older, not on newer. I admit, quite weird.

Comment: This works great in all the browsers I tested (IE9, IE11, FF, Chrome) - the FF fix seems to be no longer necessary :-)

Comment: Its not working with bootstrap.

Comment: Please note that when this solution is used, returning back to higher cell can not be done with the same effect. `:hover` selector won't work on table cells above the one selected. It may not be a problem when highlighting just the column alone.

Comment: Great trick. I would just update it a bit by using `height: 200vh;` and `width: -100vh` instead of `height: 10000px;` and `width: -5000px;`

Answer (score 19):

I have a more simple solution (Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/q3HHt/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```css
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
    width: 40px;  
    height: 40px;
}

.highlighted {
    background-color: #348A75;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('td').hover(function() {
    var t = parseInt($(this).index()) + 1;
    $('td:nth-child(' + t + ')').addClass('highlighted');
},
function() {
    var t = parseInt($(this).index()) + 1;
    $('td:nth-child(' + t + ')').removeClass('highlighted');
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/q3HHt/1/

Comment: Use `$('td:nth-child(' + t + ')', $(this).closest('table')).addClass('highlighted');` to prevent all the tables on the page from being highlighted if you have multiple.

Comment: Yes correct but a better way would be to use `id` attribute

Comment: Wouldn't that require individual listeners for each table? I just went for the simple route without editing my HTML and thought it may be useful for anyone finding this answer via Google (as I did).

Comment: $('td').hover(function() {
    $('table td:nth-child('+ ($(this).index()+1) +')').toggleClass('highlighted');
});

Comment: combine with this syntax for dynamic content hover: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14056759/5924640

Answer (score 6):

Just to extends Muhammads answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11828637/1316280), if you want to highlight the cols only in the actual table, change the jquery-code-part to:
 this jsfiddle is specific for only the actual table

**jQuery**

```
$('td').hover(function() {
    var t = parseInt($(this).index()) + 1;
    $(this).parents('table').find('td:nth-child(' + t + ')').addClass('highlighted');
},
function() {
    var t = parseInt($(this).index()) + 1;
    $(this).parents('table').find('td:nth-child(' + t + ')').removeClass('highlighted');
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q3HHt/123/

Answer (score 2):

I do not think there is a clean HTML + CSS way to do this. Javascript is an alternative, for example the [jQuery tableHover plugin](http://p.sohei.org/stuff/jquery/tablehover/demo/demo.html)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem where I had too many columns to display on screen.  VIA PHP, I turned each row into a 1 x column table.  So, n rows = n tables.  I then nested each table within a master table.  Doing so allowed me to call td:hover from my stylesheet.  Since each td held a table, it has the same effect of highlighting the a column when I mouse over it.

Answer (score -2):

You can try experimenting with `<col>` tag and `col:hover { background: red; }` style, but I doubt that it will work. Anyway, this definitely won't work in older versions of MSIE, so you will need javascript in order to do this.

Comment: `col:hover` doesn't seem to work in firefox 3.5, though `col { background-color:blue; }` does

Answer (score -4):

You can highlight the whole row with pure CSS using:

```
tr td {background-color: red;}
tr:hover td {background-color: blue;}
```

Achieving this effect for a column is impossible with this approach, as cell (td) is a child of a row (tr), not a column.

To make it work in IE7+, make sure to add doctype declaration (what you should always do anyway:)).

Comment: Doesn't answer the question