# CSS to get <th> of current <td>?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to highlight the `<th>` of the `<td>` that am currently hovering.

I can highlight the first `<tr>` using:

```css
#sheet tr:hover td:first-child { color:#000; background:#EAEAEA; }
```

Is there a way to do this for the `<th>`?

**Note** - I am using scopes for the `<th>`, like this `<th scope="col">`, can I utilize this?

**Note 2** - Or, is there a way to get the current column?

Comment: Not possible, I think, without JavaScript. Though I'd be fascinated to be proven wrong.

Comment: Is JavaScript an option for you? Since table cells are organized by rows in the DOM, there doesn't appear to be a way to select other cells in the same column using CSS. Even using `<colgroup>` and `<col>` doesn't seem to work with `:hover`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [html: hover table column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553571/html-hover-table-column)

Comment: Check out this: [jQuery tableHover](http://p.sohei.org/stuff/jquery/tablehover/demo/demo.html).  (from an answer to the [html: hover table column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553571/html-hover-table-column) question mentioned by mblase75).  example 5 is probably interesting to you.

Comment: I know I can do it using javascript, but I prefer to use CSS only for styling, when possible.

Comment: What about using js to apply a class to the th? That way you define the style in your css but handle the behavior in your js. You still keep separation of presentation and behavior.

Comment: @Alex Morales: No it does not. It applies the style to the `td`.

Comment: Ahh, you would be correct Bolt, I misread the description. I deleted the comment to avoid any confusion.

Comment: "The th of the td", which th, is it on the same line/column ? Could you paste an HTML snippet ?

Comment: When CSS4 is supported, you will be able to use `$td` to select the parent element: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: @Polynomial: That selects the `td`, not its parent `tr`. And as of January 2012, it's `tr!`, not `$tr`. The working group may very well settle for a different symbol in the later months if things get complicated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a JavaScript solution. I know you really want a CSS only answer to this, but since that's not possible I've tried to keep as much in the CSS as possible:

First your table needs to have `colgroups`. One for each column.

```
<table class="coltest">
    <colgroup><col/><col/></colgroup>
    <thead><td>Left</td><td>Right</td></thead>    
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I've also declared some simple CSS to attach to our `col` when hovered:

```css
.colhover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

And finally the jQuery to fire on hover:

```
$("table.coltest td").hover(function() {
    // get the colgroup at this elements specific index (col1, col2, etc)
    $("col").eq($(this).index()).addClass('colhover');
}, function() {
    $("col").eq($(this).index()).removeClass('colhover');
});
```

This event fires when the mouse hovers over a `td`, making the entire `colgroup` that `td` is part of yellow.

You can see an example at the [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/QgAfV/34/).

Comment: I think you meant to use `<col>`, not `<colgroup>`.

Comment: Why do you say that? Did you take a look at the jsfiddle?

Comment: The fiddle isn't relevant - you're referencing individual columns, not groups of columns, so semantically speaking, `<colgroup>` isn't the right element to use.

Comment: Okay, point taken thanks. Edited my answer, is this the proper method?

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock. I haven't used either element much before TBH.

Comment: Some improvements. Use only the col in the table, were the hover ist : `$('col', $(this).closest('table')).eq($(this).index()).addClass('colhover')`

Comment: Is there a specific reason you would want to use BOTH `col` and `colgroup` like that? It works fine using only `col`.

Comment: Also, what if I wanted to only highlight the header / footer cell, and not the entire column?

Comment: A colgroup is always implied. See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.4

Comment: Your second comment is a whole new question :) Header would be easy, just apply the style to the `td` in the `thead`, not sure about footer cell.

Answer (score 11):

As others have pointed out, this is not currently possible with just CSS. But, just as a coding exercise I tried out rotating the table with css transforms and then "unrotating" the cells, so your first child ends up being the column header...

```css
.container {
  float: left;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-240px, -260px);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-240px, -260px);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-240px, -260px);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-240px, -260px);
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-240px, -260px);
  color: #333;
}

table td, table th {
  border: solid #eee 1px;
  padding: 10px;
}

table tr:hover th:first-child { color:#000; background:#EAEAEA; }
table tr:hover td { color:#000;}

table th {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table th, table td {
  height: 200px;
  width: 20px;
}

table th span, table td span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-100px, 0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-100px, 0);
    -moz-transform-origin: top left;
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-100px, 0);
    -o-transform-origin: top left;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-100px, 0);
    -ms-transform-origin: top left;
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-100px, 0);
    transform-origin: top left;
}
```

**[view demo in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ua6p7/)**

This of course is just for fun and should **never** find its way into production. You have to add a lot of markup because many browsers go bonkers if you try to transform table cells.

In theory this should be more reliable with [`writing-mode`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/05/29/the-css-corner-writing-mode.aspx), but currently it's only supported by IE9+. It would look something like...

```css
table {
  writing-mode: TB-LR;
}

table td, table th {
  writing-mode: LR-TB;
}
```

Comment: LOL this is a completely wicked approach to the issue. I like it though, as a proof of concept. :)

Comment: Programmers on crack: The HTML story.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK it's not possible using CSS alone. You might be interested in this, although it looks like the jQuery plugin referenced in the comments is more robust.

http://css-tricks.com/row-and-column-highlighting/

Answer (score 2):

Judah is right that this isn't possible with CSS alone. The reason is that you want to target the child of a parent sibling and there is currently no way to target parents using CSS selectors.

Here's a solution using jQuery that is similar to Jivings example except that it uses your `<th>` tags (instead of colgroups) and only highlights the `<th>` instead of the whole column. The second bit of JS outputs which column you're hovering.

http://jsfiddle.net/tracyfu/Xhs4N/

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to go up the tree using CSS, only horizontally and vertically downward. Here you have all selectors you can use: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/. Nothing goes up the tree...Hope the source is credible enough ;).

Unfortunately, js is your only solution.

Answer (score 1):

As said above, there is no way to "select" parents in CSS.

The CSS4 spec provides a feature for defining the subject of a selector (which allows you to match a parent). But even with this new feature, your demand is still too complex, and the only way to achieve it, is using JavaScript.

More information on that here:

[Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: Actually, with CSS4 selectors (as of the January 2012 ED anyway), it's as simple as `th:column(td:hover)`. No need for the subject selector or `:matches()`, or JavaScript at all!