# Changing the border on table without causing a table to resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, hover

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496559/how-can-a-html-table-highlight-columns-by-changing-the-border-on-hover) earlier about a way of highlighting tables using `JavaScript` and `CSS. I'm having difficulty ensuring that the borders of the table look ok.

For example, in my table border I have set the margin to be `0`. When hovering on a column, the increased border size causes the overall table to "jump" slightly. To prevent this I tried to resize the table cells but this does not make a difference.

[image]
[image]

I'm illustrating the problem with a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/grNr8/6/. It's a little hard to see in these images but hopefully the fiddle illustrates the issue.

My `CSS` is the following:

```
table, td {
    background-color: white;   
    border: 0px solid white;
    border-collapse: collapse;   
}
```

When highlighting the column, a border of pixel thickness `2` is chosen. I tried experimenting with changing the cell size using `$('td').css({height: '29px'});` (and varying from `26 - 29`) but it does not change the effect. The `Javascript` I am using to highlight is based mainly on an answer to my previous question:

```
$('td').hover(function() {
    var t = parseInt($(this).index()) + 1;
    $('td:nth-child(' + t + ')').first().addClass('highlightedTop');
    $('td:nth-child(' + t + ')').addClass('highlighted')
    $('td:nth-child(' + t + ')').last().removeClass('highlighted').addClass('x');

    $('td').css({
        height: '39px'
    });

    if (t > 1) {
        var t1 = t - 1;
        $('td:nth-child(' + t1 + ')').addClass('highlightedPrev');
        $('td:nth-child(' + t1 + ')').last().removeClass('highlightedPrev');

    }
}, function() {
    var t = parseInt($(this).index()) + 1;
    $('td:nth-child(' + t + ')').removeClass('highlighted ');
    $('td:nth-child(' + t + ')').first().removeClass('highlightedTop');
    $('td:nth-child(' + t + ')').last().removeClass('highlightedBottom');
    $('td:nth-child(' + t + ')').last().removeClass('x');
    if (t > 1) {
        var t1 = t - 1;
        $('td:nth-child(' + t1 + ')').removeClass('highlightedPrev');
    }
});​
```

Is it possible to resize the cells for smoother viewing, or should I be using a different approach? I have experimented with using a white border thickness of `1px` but I end up with strange joins at the corners and un-symmetric borders at the extremities.

Comment: Is using `outline` an option?  The down side is that all 4 sides must have a stroke applied to them, but the up side is that it doesn't impact the element's width like border does.

Comment: Yes - it could be (I was not aware of it). Can it be used with a table?

Comment: Works on just about anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If outline doesn't work for you, using a 2px solid transparent border on the default state can also work:

```
table, td {
    background-color: white;   
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    border-collapse: collapse;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/grNr8/7/

Answer (score 1):

Could you overlay the table cell on hover with a transparent png that looks like a border?

Answer (score 1):

Put a DIV in the TD and style the DIV instead. You can manipulate the size of the DIV to allow for the border, whereas you cannot for a table cell.

Comment: ok - I will try this out. I also just thought that it might be simpler to overlay a set of divs matching in size with the columns which I could style.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a border and add a border, things get messed up. Instead if you *do have* a border and *change it's colour*, the outcome is much better. No jumping, to say the least. If your JSFiddle example represents what you really want to do (that being solid bg-coloured td's), that's what I would do.

```
.a{background-color: red; border: 2px solid red; }
.b{background-color: green; border: 2px solid green;}
.c{background-color: orange; border: 2px solid orange;}
```

See full example: http://jsfiddle.net/grNr8/9/

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is easiest to just always use a border and only change the color. The solution is so simple that I think I missed some details of the question:

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nakVN/1/)**

```
.a{
    background-color: red;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
.b{
    background-color: green;
    border: 2px solid green;
}
.c{
    background-color: orange;
    border: 2px solid orange;
}
```