# jquery .hover not working on AJAX rendered elements

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have some elements that are created from an AJAX call.  Within those elements, there is a child element that when hovered needs to show another child element that was dynamically created.  When I run the `.hover` jquery in a fiddle, it works fine.  When I implement it in my code, it doesn't want to work.

I was wondering if it depends on when the `.hover` script is loaded vs when the elements are loaded from AJAX.  Does one need to go before the other?  Should a `.promise` be enacted to wait for the AJAX elements to load before the `.hover` script is run?

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7dcuh/14/) of my example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I understand your question to mean that you are attaching an event to an element that may not exist yet. Instead of binding to the element (which `.hover()` is shorthand for) you should delegate it to a permanent container element. You can do this with either `delegate()` or `.on()` depending on jQuery version.

Here's what it would look like in your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7dcuh/15/

Answer (score 10):

For dynamically generated elements, events should be delegated from one of static parents of the element or document object, you can use `on` or `delegate` method.

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).next('.show').fadeIn(800);
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).next('.show').delay(800).fadeOut(800);
    }
}, '.touch');
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try to insert the script inside the ajax response.
like

```
 <script> </script>
```

or you serve the script when the ajax call is complete or success

```
jQuery.ajax({

success:function(){jQuery('selector').yourfunction();},

        });
```

if you dont, the script will run and not find the selectors in the dom and the script wont run again

Answer (score 1):

Check out deferred events using the .on() function. You can do an event like:

```
$('#parent').on('hover', '.touch', function() {
    $(this).next('.show').fadeIn(800);
},
function(){
    $(this).next('.show').delay(800).fadeOut(800);
});
```

OR, the pure CSS solution would be:

```
.touch + .show {
    display:none;
}
.touch:hover + .show {
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute .hover script in success callback of AJAX after you insert elements.

Answer (score 0):

If the content is generated with Ajax, you should use [livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the correct answer but I've found elements that are created within a function. Need their selector to be declared within the function. Like so:

```
function createEle(){
    $('#element').after('<div id="newEle"><div id="inner" style="display:none;"></div></div>');
    $('#newEle').hover(function(){
        $('#inner','#newEle').show();
    },function(){
        $('#inner','#newEle').hide();
    });
}
```