# Angularjs highlighting columns ng-table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ngtable

I am trying to figure out how I can highlight a column using [ng-table](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table) directive for Angular. Though my understanding on this directive is that in the current setup it is not capable of achieving what I am looking to do, so I will have to modify it myself.

I'd like to know if anyone has had any success with getting table column highlighting working with angular sorting and ng-repeat, it doesn't necessarily have to be done with ng-table, but any example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Checkout the second answer if all you're looking for is a hover style. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553571/html-hover-table-column

Comment: If you're in an `ng-repeat` of sorts, you could use `ng-class="{ highlighted: $index == 1 }"` to add a `highlighted` class to the element. An example in CSS would be `.highlighted{background:red}`.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your table definition, add table-hover class, for example:

< table ng-table="myTable" class="table table-hover table-striped table-condensed table-bordered" >

2. Customize color in app.css

   .table-hover > tbody > tr:hover {
   background-color: #dadada;
   }

Answer (score -1):

Give your table a custom class:

```
 <table ng-table="usersTable" class="table my-custom-table-class">
     <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
         <td data-title="'Name'" sortable="'name'">{{user.name}}</td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

Then, in the CSS add the following:

```
.my-custom-table-class tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #dddddd; 
}
```

the `#dddddd` is the color of the highlight.

Comment: I think he asked how to highlight the whole column, but not the row. It has to be a Javascript way due to the selector cannot select a column. Am I right?